# Can you get a count of S3 objects with a given prefix without iterating through them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Say I have a prefix `s3://foo/`. I want to know how many objects are under this. If I do:

```
num = 0
for i in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="foo/"):
   num += 1
```

It is too slow, because there are many objects under this directory. Is there a faster way to do it, without iterating?

Comment: You could simplify the code with `num = len(list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="foo/")))`, but the main time-taker is the API calls. You'll either need those calls, or use the options mentioned by @Marcin below.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to query [NumberOfObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html) CloudWatch metric for the given bucket.

For more detailed analyses, e.g. for different prefixes, its best to request [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html).

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: @Dommondke Please check boto3 docs on [get_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data).

Comment: Maybe mention that you can't just use `len()` because of the limitations on boto and AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the most efficient way to count them (without using CloudWatch metrics) is using paginator that returns `KeyCount` and using JMESPath it only returns count of each page:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
count_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket', Prefix='foo/').search('KeyCount')
total_keys = sum(count for count in count_iterator)
```